# deserialize object that contains list of int as property

Tags: json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to Deserialize a Json into my object using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.
My json is:`{"SelectedContentsID[]":"31807,32493,39517","pageSize":"20","SisconContentSubDialogEnum":"0","searchCriteria":"","pageIndex":"1"}`

and the respective class is:

```
[DataContract]
public class ContentGetHandlerDTO : ListBaseHandlerDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "SelectedCourseId")]
    public int SelectedCourseId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<int> SelectedContentsID { get; set; }
    public ContentGetHandlerDTO() {
        this.SelectedContentsID = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();
    }
}
```

the ListBaseHandlerDto is just a class that contains some commons properties.
The problem is, the deserializer method is just ignoring the list of int and bringing a null list.

Answer (score 0):

Your Json looks incorrect, it should look like this:

```
{
"SelectedContentsID":[31807,32493,39517],
"pageSize":"20",
"SisconContentSubDialogEnum":"0",
"searchCriteria":"",
"pageIndex":"1"
}
```

specifically look at your SelectedContentsID,
you had:

```
"SelectedContentsID[]":"31807,32493,39517"
```

when a json int array should look like this:

```
"SelectedContentsID":[31807,32493,39517]
```

here is a pretty good reference if you ever get confused - http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: Thanks Zach, it was happening due to the serialization from a Dictionary to Json, using JavaScriptSerializer.
Now, I`m facing other problem: the Deserializer is throwing: "Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]."

Comment: if this is the correct answer, please mark it as such by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: I would be happy to help, but you need to mark this as the correct answer, and start a new question, as the issue is now different. :)